# How to properly add a external library manually to a nexus local repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I am trying to deploy an application using a local repository that is running through nexus.
What is the proper procedure to add manually an external jar library file?
I've tried to do it using the Nexus 3rd party repository but I am afraid that I am doing something wrong because I cannot use this library when I code.
What are the proper fields that I must use to fill the GAV definition?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "I cannot use this library when I code"? That suggests that you were able to upload the 3rd party jar into Nexus, but that your Maven settings were wrong. What Nexus URL were you using when running the Maven build?

Comment: The ide does not find the packages.For example com.zybnet package cannot be found (so that I can use com.zybnet.autocomplete.server.AutocompleteField class)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am answering my own question to help others with similar problems.
I used custom maven coordinates in the GAV definition.
For example I used

groupId : com.thirdparty.vaadin
artifactId : vaadin-autocomplete
version : 1.0.0

Then all I had to do was to add these coordinates as a dependency to my project.
So I just added the following code to my pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.thirdparty.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-autocomplete</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: And what repository did you add it to? Because as long as you have the coordinates in the repo and the pom right.. it will work just fine with the 3rd party repo. In fact that is where you should probably upload to..

Comment: The jar is uploaded to the 3rd party repo.